# JavaFX how to count errors made typing

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make my first app an have hit a roadblock. The app is basically just a simple typing practice app where the user is given a string which they copy. I am trying to implement a count that counts the number of errors made by the user.

Currently I have code that uses a listener to observe the string the user is inputting to a text area. I have an error count that is added to every time the users string does not equal the provided string, the issue with this is I want to only add 1 to the count for every error made. For example, currently if you make a mistake and type 2 wrong characters the error count will go up to 3 as the code runs every time a key is pressed meaning it counts the 2 wrong chars and 1 backspace to remove them and I would like this to only add 1 to the error count.

The code I have currently is below:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane errorStatus;
    @FXML
    private TextArea inputTextArea;
    @FXML
    public TextArea generatedText;

    private String userText;
    private String thePassage;
    private Integer errorCount = 0;
    private Boolean errorCheck = false;

    timer time = new timer();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        thePassage = PassageData.getPassage();
        generatedText.setText(thePassage);

        inputTextArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, 
            String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!inputTextArea.getText().isEmpty()) {
                time.start();
            }

            userText = newValue;

            if (userText.equals("") || userText.equals(null)) {
                errorStatus.setStyle(
                        "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, white, white); -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
            } else if (thePassage.regionMatches(0, userText, 0, userText.length())) {
                errorCheck = false;
                errorStatus.setStyle(
                        "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, green, white); -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
            } else {
                errorCheck = true;
                errorStatus.setStyle(
                        "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, red, white); -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
            }

            if (userText.equals(thePassage)) {
                thePassage = PassageData.getPassage();
                generatedText.setText(thePassage);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    inputTextArea.clear();
                });
                errorStatus.setStyle(
                        "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, white, white); -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
                time.pause();
            }

            if (errorCheck) {
                errorCount++;
                System.out.println("Error count = " + errorCount);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You have just discovered the reason almost no application performs validation as the user types.  Wait until the user is *done typing* before you validate.  The most obvious way is to have a Button with text like “Submit” or something similar.  Another, less obvious way is to set the TextField’s [action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#setOnAction(javafx.event.EventHandler)), so validation is only done when the user presses Enter.

Comment: I thought about doing this but if I understand correctly the issue with this is I want to warn the user whenever they make an error so they can correct it as they type. If I used a button such as submit then I wouldn't be able to do this, or am I missing something?

Comment: I am basically trying to make something very similar to how https://play.typeracer.com/ works.

Comment: use a TextFormatter: in its filter you can do whatever you want, f.i. counting errors in new input and ignoring changes from cleanup effort

Comment: @VGR there might be (and actually are) contexts where on-commit validation is the right thingy to do, but there are also contexts where we want on-typing validation ... which in fx is easily possible with a TextFormatter: we can choose whether we want to interfere directly and reject the change or just add some error marker or do whatever we need to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Repeating (across several questions) Don't use low-level listeners if the framework provides higher-level support!

In this context, the high level support for fine-grained changes of text input is a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html), in particular its filter property. Such a filter will be notified whenever the text changes in any way (including caret navigation) and even allows to modify the change - all *before* the textProperty is changed.

A raw snippet that will count errors against a given text - for context see [the Zephyr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733254/203657)

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
    if (c.isAdded()) {
        // tbd: guard against off-range
        int pos = c.getRangeStart();
        if (!c.getText().equals(target.substring(pos, pos + 1))) {
            errorCount.set(errorCount.get() +1);
        }
    }
    return c;
};

textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(filter));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I was looking for. The only thing now is I only want it to add 1 to the error when the user starts going wrong. So say they typed 3 wrong characters in a row, only 1 would be added to error count. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: that's simple logic ... all you need is a bit of keeping track of chances and counting ... leaving to you <g>

Answer (score 0):

You will want to setup a change listener for the `TextArea`, but then compare each character of your input `String` with each character of the entered text.

The MCVE below demonstrates this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        IntegerProperty errorCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        String target = "This is the sample text to be typed correctly.";
        Label instructions = new Label(target);

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label errorsLabel = new Label();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Errors:"), errorsLabel);

        // Bind the label to errorcount
        errorsLabel.textProperty().bind(errorCount.asString());

        // Listen for changes to the textArea text and check again target string
        textArea.textProperty().addListener((observableValue, s, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                errorCount.set(getErrorCount(target, newValue));
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(instructions, textArea, hbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int getErrorCount(String target, String entered) {

        int errors = 0;

        // Compare each character in the strings
        char[] targetChars = target.toCharArray();
        char[] enteredChars = entered.toCharArray();

        // Starting at the beginning of the entered text, check that each character, in order, matches the target String
        for (int i = 0; i < enteredChars.length; i++) {
            if (enteredChars[i] != targetChars[i]) {
                errors++;
            }
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

So what is happening here is each time a character is typed (or deleted) in the `TextArea`, the `getErrorCount()` method compares the entered text to the `target` String. If any characters are incorrect, it will increase the error count.

This is a lot like the "Submit" button idea from the comments above, but is performed each time the text changes in the `TextArea`, without a need for the extra button.

Comment: thanks for the mcve :) Though your approach is suboptimal: always go for the highest abstraction available, here a TextFormatter